# MySQL error in a view #1351: View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter

Tags: mysql, row-number

I am trying to create a view containing a variable, in order to have a column with a unique index such it is suggested in the most voted answer of the question: [ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

The solution works in a simple select, but When I try to convert it in a view executing below sentence then I get the MySQL error.

```
CREATE VIEW `new_view` AS
SELECT t.*, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

My view contain several joins but data displayed can be resumen in below  registers, as can be seen some registers are repeated which is correct:

```
 col1   col2   col3  
 '23', 'bla', 'bla'  
 '23', 'bla', 'bla'
 '67', 'fgh', 'qwe'
 '67', 'we4', 'cdf'
 '70', 'nhn', 'yui'
```

What I want to get is:

```
 rank col1   col2   col3  
 1    '23', 'bla', 'bla'  
 2    '23', 'bla', 'bla'
 3    '67', 'fgh', 'qwe'
 4    '67', 'we4', 'cdf'
 5    '70', 'nhn', 'yui'
```

As a previous step to get below result:

```
 rank2 col1   col2   col3  
 1    '23', 'bla', 'bla'  
 2    '23', 'bla', 'bla'
 1    '67', 'fgh', 'qwe'
 2    '67', 'we4', 'cdf'
 1    '70', 'nhn', 'yui'
```

What is the best way to create that index column in a view if MySQL does not allow variable usage inside views?

Comment: You can't base a view on that query.  Also, side note, the rank you define is meaningless without an `ORDER BY` clause.  Your workaround would be to generate rank using another method.

Comment: Can you suggest any other method? In the view where I am trying to add that rank/index column there are repeated registers

Comment: Edit your question and include data and your actual query, or better yet a minimal version of it.  There are many ways to generate a row number, but only if your data permits it.

Comment: I have edited the question to better explain my problem.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this without session variables, because you have duplicate rows.  You could try selecting your current query into a temp table.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I will try to first to include a column to differ all registers so I will be able to use the other suggested workarounds for ROW_NUMBER in MySQL